# aws cloud-formation create secret with variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-secrets-manager

I am trying to take username and password from user as input parameters and create the secret in secret manager.
Using `${Username}` doesnt seem to replace and could not find a documentation on how to go about this. Is it even supported? if not, any recommended workarounds?

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Resources:
  MySecret:
    Type: 'AWS::SecretsManager::Secret'
    Properties:
      Description: 'My example secret'
      GenerateSecretString:
        SecretStringTemplate: '{"username": "${Username}", "password": "${Password}"}'
        PasswordLength: 16
        ExcludePunctuation: true
      Tags:
        - Key: 'Name'
          Value: 'MySecret'
Parameters:
  Username:
    Type: String
    Description: 'Username for the secret'
  Password:
    Type: String
    Description: 'Password for the secret'
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have wanted `SecretString` instead of `GenerateSecretString`.

The `GenerateSecretString` property generates random passwords for you. The template lets you specify text that contains the password, but not the password itself. If you specify `SecretStringTemplate`, you also need to provide `GenerateStringKey`.

This template:

```yaml
Resources:
  Secret:
    Type: AWS::SecretsManager::Secret
    Properties: 
      GenerateSecretString:
        GenerateStringKey: password
        SecretStringTemplate: '{"username": "admin"}'
```

Creates a secret that looks like this:

`{"password":"q0*99P1dd46@_K*zW#pA+nK5fhkqA!/u","username":"admin"}`